# How to compare 2 csv files in protractor typescript?

Tags: typescript, csv, protractor, comparison

I am trying to compare 2 csv files in my protractor automation scripts using typescript language.

I have read online about some solutions but found no one.

NA

Comment: i'm not ready to give exact answer that would work but look into `fs.createReadStream()` which per my understanding converts any file into binary, which later on can be compared

Answer (score 0):

I used [CSV Parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parser) to parse file and load into memory. Once you get those in memory with simple for loop you can compare them.

Please note this return object with name as column header and value will be a value of that cell

```
const csv = require('csv-parser')
const fs = require('fs')
const results = [];

fs.createReadStream('data.csv')
          .pipe(csv())
          .on('data', (data) => results.push(data))
          .on('end', () => {
            console.log(results);
            // [
            //   { NAME: 'Daffy Duck', AGE: '24' },
            //   { NAME: 'Bugs Bunny', AGE: '22' }
            // ]
          });
```